# Negative bottom margin not working in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, google-chrome, jquery-animate

I have a div that is hidden from view:

```
 position:fixed; 
 bottom:-240px;
```

***UPDATE II ***

doubling the bottom from bottom:-240px to -480px and then adjusting the animation height has hidden the div in IE9 and eliminated the flickering in Chrome and Safari. Overflow:hidden is not working for some reason in IE9 and I cannot get the div to close in IE9 by clicking on the close button (mediaclose).***

I use jquery animate to show the div, which is accessed when clicking on a link:

```
 $("#media").click(function () {
 $("#mediadetails").animate({height: "425px"}, 1000);
```

and also to hide it:

```
 $('#mediaclose').click(function() {
 $('#mediadetails').animate({height: "0px"}, 2000);
```

Comment: You say it works in IE then you say it doesn't work in IE, which is it?

Comment: sorry, I meant it works fine in firefox

Comment: Are you looking for something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/bhrj8/ (click anywhere to toggle the div).

Comment: similar, yes. But I have a close button (#mediaclose) in the right corner of the div that closes the div and a link in the upper right corner of the page that opens it. I cannot get the div to close in IE, but all other browsers are fine

Comment: It might also help if you tell us which version of IE you're having problems with.

Comment: Really, I just need to get the div to close now when clicking the close button. Works in all browsers except IE 9 for some reason.

Comment: And recreate the problem in a site like jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$('#mediadetails').animate({height: 0}, 2000);
$('#mediadetails').animate({height: 425}, 2000);
```

Comment: are you meaning use the first part for the open and the second part for the close?

Comment: @user1667057 no use the first part for the close and the second part for the open